# Gradle gretty jetty not working in Debug

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gradle, jetty, gretty

I am using the Windows OS, JDK 1.7, Gradle 3.0, IDE Eclipse mars and jetty 8.1.5.v20120716.

Note: I am using gretty plugin too

```
gretty {
    port = http_port
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    contextPath = ''
    classPath = sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs
    servletContainer = 'jetty9' //tomcat7 or tomcat8
     httpPort = 8081 
     servicePort = 8082 
     statusPort = 8083
}
```

The behavior is same in all the options which I have tried, it is just hanging there at the port 5005 statement, it is not even loading the application also. I am using Spring annotation based and class type we initializer "AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer"

I tried in the following options. appStartDebug, appRunDebug, jettyStartDebug and jettyRunDebug.

```
C:\project>echo %GRADLE_OPTS%
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9999,server=y,suspend=n

C:\project>gradle jettyStartDebug
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9999
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 10 busy and 19 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
'5e5ca94'
:prepareInplaceWebAppFolder UP-TO-DATE
:createInplaceWebAppFolder UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:prepareInplaceWebAppClasses UP-TO-DATE
:prepareInplaceWebApp UP-TO-DATE
:jettyStartDebug
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

Please someone help me on this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must create a remote debug session.

In eclipse: Run > Debug Configuration > Remote Java Application
Then right clic and create New. Don't launch yet.

[image: Remote Debug]

Then go the console and start your project with: gradle jettyRunDebug, when it stops on "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005", there launch your debug since IDE, with the configuration previously created.

It must go into debug mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it is working. You really made my day.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the debug options from `%GRADLE_OPTS%` and do

```
gretty {
    debug = true
    debugSuspend = false
    debugPort = 9999
    ...
}
```

See [StartBaseTask.groovy](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/blob/master/libs/gretty/src/main/groovy/org/akhikhl/gretty/StartBaseTask.groovy) and [AppStartTask.groovy](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/blob/master/libs/gretty/src/main/groovy/org/akhikhl/gretty/AppStartTask.groovy)